# Like a discussion board item using powershell

Tags: 2013, development, discussion-board, like

I want to write a power-shell script to like a discussion item by a user. now i tried the following :-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://**/" 
$list=$web.Lists.TryGetList("News");
$user = $web.EnsureUser("\user.test");
$doc = $list.GetItemById(330);
$likedBy = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldUserValue($web,  $user.ID, $user.LoginName);

$doc["DescendantLikesCount"] = "3";
$doc["LikesCount"] = "3";
$doc["LikedBy"].Add($likedBy);
$doc.UpdateOverwriteVersion() ;
```

now currently the like count will be set to 3, but when i hover over the "like", the popup will only list one user as follow, where i have like the item using the UI:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please? how i can add the user to show inside the users popup ?
Thanks